# Why is the MQTT connect call called repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mqtt

The below code executes fine, however the connect call apparently is called every second, as the console fills up with the message below. In this minimal example this might not seem like a problem, but when adding more code in the connect call it is not beneficial that this is the case.

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
var mqtt_client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://XXXXXXXXXX:2883", {
  clientId: "trigger-broker",
  username: "XXXXX",
  password: "XXXXX"
});

mqtt_client.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Client connected successfully");
});
```

I tried changing the qos of the client and trying out with a different instance of my broker. Also I upgraded from mqtt 4.0.1 to 4.3.7 which didn't change anything.

Edit: This is the beginning of the broker code

```
  broker.on("publish", async function (packet, client) {
    if (packet.payload) {
      let payload = packet.payload.toString();
      let topic = "";

      try {
        payload = JSON.parse(payload);
        topic = packet.topic;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error parsing payload", e);
        return;
      }
```

Comment: Please provide more info (what broker, broker logs, what else is connecting to the broker etc). A common cause of similar issues is another client connecting to the broker with the same client ID (this causes the broker to drop existing connections for that client ID, dropped client reconnects so broker drops the other client, infinite loop..).

Comment: What else have you done to try and debug this? Have you added `on('disconnect',...)` or `on('error',...)` event handlers to try and gather more information?

Comment: @hardillb Yes, I extended my script by now to use disconnect and error signals, but they are not getting triggered. I still only have console logs from the connect

Comment: @Brits the broker should be fine, it never dropped other clients as far as I can tell. I added the code above.

Comment: @Brits I investigated the logs and you were right, it throws an error on connect, because the payload is a string and can't be parsed as JSON

Comment: I added offline, closed and reconnected signals as well, which are all called. However other clients don't disconnect

Comment: You need to provide more info e.g. the broker logs, error codes etc.

Comment: @Brits The broker logs are empty, there are no error messages there, also no error code or similar.

Comment: Restarted the broker today and the problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: "The broker logs are empty" then turn up the logging level :-). Unfortunately as you did not say what broker you were using there was no way to know what options were available. Glad that you seem to have a fix (but concerning that a restart was needed).